# Facebook dialog share

Tags: facebook

We have an app that when our users click **share** we then forward the user to  `facebook.com/dialog/share`  to share our link.

I need to add this to email and I'm trying to test.  Is there a way to test and see the actual post without having to post to my FB account?  I want to post the message and link and then test clicking the link on the post without having to post to my personal FB account

Comment: What’s the problem with posting to your own account? Make it a private share if the content is too embarrassing … or share it in a private message, or to a (test) page you are an admin of …

Comment: yes, i feel stupid.  That's the problem when one doesn't do much FB.  All I had to do is post to myself.  Thanks CBroe!